# How to use svg-crowbar on specific svgelement

Tags: javascript, svg

All:

What I want to do is using JS to save specific svg to a file( it can be svg, or other formats).

Some posts suggest svg-crowbar, I tried the example on its page(http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/ ), it is amazing and work well, but I do not know how to control it to download specific SVG on my page with JS.

Could anyone give me an example of how to call svg-crowbar API to download specific SVG element on the page.

Thanks

Comment: @Dinesh I finally give it up in this way, instead,  I use html2canvas and manualy canvas operation. The drawback of html2canvas is it can not properly handle SVG to image(only html part can be rendered), so I need a separated part for converting SVG, one thing to notice is the external css need to compiled into inline style.  After I got both parts(basically one canvas passed by html2canvas and one Image object), I composite them together and convert into an image.(Above just applies to my project case, you may need certain adjust and figure out how to apply to your own situation)

Comment: @Dinesh  The posts I refer to are: [1] http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/     [2] http://mrcoles.com/blog/canvas-composite-operations-demo-animation/     Hope these help.